# mysql_query returns false after successfully executing query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange bug where I call an insert query, it executes successfully (the row appears in the DB) but `mysql_query` returns `false`.  It only returns false when a particular field contains an underscore or dash (or probably some other chars but these are the two I've run into so far).

```
"INSERT INTO Hoopoes (name, owner, dbuser, dbpass, package) VALUES "
                        ."('".$this->config['hname']."', '".$this->config['email']."','".$db_prefix.$db_username."','$db_userpass',"
                        ."'".$this->config['package']."')"
```

So this is the query.  It fails when `config['hname']` contains `_` or `-`.  I don't understand why.  The row appears in the DB, but `mysql_query` still returns false.  Any insight would be much appreciated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Have you checked mysql_error() after it returns false to see if that gives a clue?

Comment: SQL_injection shouldn't be an issue here.  The values in the config array have been long since pruned for potential injection threats.

I'm using MyISAM  sorry should've included that

Comment: mysql_error is "no database selected" ....  so then how is the row appearing in the db??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mus select the database after connect and before any query:

```
// Connect...
mysql_connect("server", "user", "pass");
// ...and select the database!
mysql_select_db("database");

// Now you're good to go. :)
```

You can use your INSERT query without select a database when you specify the schema, like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`table` VALUES (...);
```

Comment: ya, I did select it earlier in the script.  this isn't the first DB call that's made.  the config array gets pulled from the DB and a few other queries get made prior to this one.  Either way, I threw a redundant mysql_select_db in there directly above the query and that seemed to shut it up.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

It's good to check what mysql_error() returns.
In my case it was 'table database_name.table_name doesn't exist'. That has given me a clue and after second check I realized that i've created table_name in PHPMyAdmin in another database than database_name :P

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..  this was a strange one.  The query worked and successfully inserted apparently without a database selected.  I added a mysql_select_db call directly above the query, and now it works just the same, but the query returns true.

Strange

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the SQL query is successfully executed doesn't means it should return a TRUE. It only returns TRUE if the queries are executed in a proper order. Hope that is why you are getting a FALSE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-query.html

Comment: This was almost 7 years ago ;)    And I found the solution.  Thanks though!